# How to look into code generated by webpack programmatically to search for strings such as Component, useState, or render?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

The code expected to check if a webpage is using ReactJS:

```
if(!!window.React ||
   !!document.querySelector('[data-reactroot], [data-reactid]'))
  console.log('React.js');
```

doesn't work for a simple app created by using `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Can we look into code generated by webpack, to determine if it has React code in it?  For example, is it true that even if the code is obfuscated, some API or property / method names will stay there, such as `Component`, `render`, `useState`, and `useEffect`?  Is there a way to look into webpack generated code programmatically to search for these strings?  Can we do it once and simply in dev console, without searching in all the different script files? Some website may be linking to 35 `.js` files).

(and better yet, if we can find out the version number.  There is a `version` property in the `React` object but I am not sure if it'd be obfuscated -- property names probably are not obfuscated?)

Comment: Do you want to do it in build time or in run time?

Comment: @NirG if it is build time... I know what I am building... I want to do it at run time

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [`source-map`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), which allows you to include the original source mapped to the 'obfuscated' webpack code. This will allow you to see the original source code in your brower, and facilitate debugging.

Comment: isn't it possible the source-map is not deployed to the server though?